# IntStream to sum a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, java-8

What is the syntax for using IntStream to sum a range of elements in a 2D array?

For a 1D array, I use the following syntax:

```
int totalElementsInArray = 0;

totalElementsInarray = IntStream.of(myArray).sum();
```

So for instance, say I have a 2D array:

```
int[][] my2DArray = new int[17][4];
```

What is the syntax when using IntStream for summing columns 0-16 on row 0?

```
int totalElementsInArray = 0;

totalElementsInarray = IntStream.of(my2DArray[0 through 16][0]).sum();
```

Answer (score 8):

You just need to map each sub-array to an `int` by taking the first element:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*; 

class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[][] data = {
            { 1, 2, 3 },
            { 4, 5, 6 }
        };

        int sum = Arrays.stream(data)
                        .mapToInt(arr -> arr[0])
                        .sum();
        System.out.println(sum); // 5, i.e. data[0][0] + data[1][0]
    } 
}
```

In other words:

- Transform `data` to a `Stream<int[]>` (i.e. a stream of simple `int` arrays)
- Map each array to its first element, so we end up with an `IntStream`
- Sum that stream

I prefer this approach over the approaches using `range`, as there seems no need to consider the indexes of the sub-arrays. For example, if you only had an `Iterable<int[]> arrays` you could still use `StreamSupport.stream(arrays.spliterator(), false).mapToInt(arr -> arr[0]).sum()`, whereas the range approach would require iterating multiple times.

Comment: Plus one for the speed you managed to convert a brilliant answer to a different question to a brilliant answer to this one! `Iterable` doesn't have a `stream` method though...

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it would be to create a `IntStream` over the indexes

```
IntStream.range(0, my2DArray.length).map(i -> my2DArray[i][0]).sum();
```

or only keep the first row of the result of [`Arrays.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-):

```
Arrays.stream(my2DArray).mapToInt(a -> a[0]).sum();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```
IntStream.range(0, 17)
         .map(i -> my2DArray[i][0])
         .sum();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    int[][] data = {
            { 1, 2, 3 },
            { 4, 5, 6 },
            { 7, 8, 9 }
    };

    int total = Arrays.stream(data)
            .mapToInt(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr).sum())
            .sum();
    System.out.println(total);
```

Comment: As its 2D array ( array of array) we need to use Arrays of stream 2 times to get all elements sum.

Comment: Looks Ok, but how different is it from the second answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36070426/1684254? If your answer is exactly the same as another one, it is better to upvote

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29893438)